# Why google shuts down my residents instance even the minimum idling instance set to 1

Tags: google-app-engine, dynamic, shutdown, instances

I've just started playing with GAE. Today I just noticed that GAE shuts down my residents instance even the minimum idling instance set to 1, which causes a cold-start for the next request.

So here is the settings:
1. one simple frontend app, no other stuff
2. minimum idling instance set to 1
3. billing enabled and no charges, which means the shutdown is not because of budget
issue
4. an outside java process making a simple request every hour

From the instance chart in the admin console, it's obvious that at -1.5hour and -0.5hour time point, GAE spawned another dynamic instance to serve the outside request or something, and shutdown both the residents and dynamic instances after 15 minutes. The zero-instance situation remained for another 15 minutes until a residents instance was created again.

Who has similar issues or any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that has happened to us all. *Resident instances* do not shutdown, unless manually forced to. From GAE Console:

*Idle Instances* (another way to referring to *resident instance*) are pre-loaded with your application code, so when a new Instance is needed, it can serve traffic immediately, thus, avoiding high latency during load spikes.

*Resident instances* start serving pages, if they become too busy they become a *dynamic instance* and another *resident instance* is started in its place. For that reason you will sometimes see the age of a resident instance younger than their dynamic counterparts.